# Why is the Buddha called "Kinsman of the Sun"?

Tags: pali-canon, the-buddha, gautama-buddha

In some suttas like SN 22.95 and Snp 4.14, the Buddha is called the Kinsman of the Sun (*ādiccabandhu*).

Why is he called the Kinsman of the Sun?

What is the origin of the term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.  I don't have any pali references at the moment, but there is this concept of [solar dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_dynasty).

> ... Buddhist texts include Shuddodhana, Gautama Buddha, and Rahula in
> their accounts of the Ikshvaku dynasty